# Invisible cursor in Ubuntu 15.10 and other versions

Tags: mouse, cursor

I installed 15.10 recently and found invisible cursor problem as reported by many other users.

I started to seek for causes and solutions for this problem but tried nothing yet. It is interesting that every first boot the cursor will be gone but still working as I can do whatever I want by mouse clicking. After reboot, everything is back to normal.

I consider this as an issue related to hardware detecting. I plugged 2 mice at the same time, one wired and one wireless. The problem had never shown up before I plugged a second mouse, so I unplug the wireless mouse and shut down the computer. The problem disappears when the computer is turned on again.

Since the problem is reproducible and solvable, anyone could study the source code of relative functions and improve it will be appreciated I think.

Cheers